# Why does this assembly program output the same string twice?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, caesar-cipher, irvine32

This Caesar cipher program makes de-cipher string (length is always 10) and output is output.txt file.
for example below code make .txt file,

```
ILIKEASSEM

HOWAREYOUU
```

but when i run this code, the file is

```
ILIKEASSEM

ILIKEASSEM
```

I can't know what is wrong even though debug by visual studio 2017  (MASM) debugger (T.T)

what is wrong...?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
Num_Str DWORD 2
;;key = 10
Cipher_Str BYTE "SVSUOKCCOW",0 
        BYTE "RYGKBOIYEE",0
filename    BYTE"output.txt", 0
fileHandle  DWORD ?
BUFFER_SIZE = 12
buffer  BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
L   BYTE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0
Decipher    BYTE "QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", 0
count       DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

    mov     edx, OFFSET filename
    call    CreateOutputFile        
    mov     fileHandle, eax         



    mov     ecx, Num_Str
    mov     esi, 0                  

    L1:
        push    ecx                 
        mov     ecx, 11                 

    L2: 
        mov     al, Cipher_Str[esi]     
        sub     al, 65                  


        movzx   ax, al                  
        movzx   eax, ax                 

        mov     edi, eax                



        mov     al, Decipher[edi]       

        mov     buffer[esi], al     
        inc     esi

    loop    L2


        mov     bl, 13
        mov     buffer[esi], bl

        inc     esi
        mov     bl, 10
        mov     buffer[esi], bl


        mov     eax,fileHandle
        mov     edx,OFFSET buffer
        mov     ecx, BUFFER_SIZE
        call    WriteToFile



        pop     ecx



    loop    L1




    mov     eax, fileHandle 
    call    CloseFile


exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What did you observe in your debugging?  You ought to be able to see what bytes are stored in `buffer`, where they came from, and how they were computed.  Which part of this were you not able to follow?

Comment: Since you use `esi` for both reading and writing, the decoded version of the second string will be placed after the first one in the buffer (which is overflowed).

Comment: If you simplify your code it would be fewer instructions to follow.  e.g. the code in L2: could do `movzx eax, byte ptr Cipher_Str[esi]` / `mov   al, Decipher[eax-65]` (then store AL into `buffer` and increment esi).  There's no need to zero extend in 2 steps, from byte to word and then to dword, and you can do it for free as part of a load.  (In fact it's *more* efficient to do a movzx load than to merge a new AL into the low byte of the old EAX.

Answer (score 1):

You are overflowing the 12 byte *buffer* **even before** starting the 2nd iteration of the outer loop *L1*. You decipher the 10 characters but also the terminating zero (which you should pass over) and then add carriage return and linefeed. That's a total of 13 bytes!
You further overflow it because you don't reset the `ESI` register.

A possible solution is to reset to zero the offset register that indexes the output buffer with every iteration of the outer loop, and use a different index register to refer to the cipher strings that are 11 bytes apart.

```
    BUFFER_SIZE = 12
    ...
    mov     esi, offset Cipher_Str            
L1:
    xor     edi, edi            ; EDI=0
L2: 
    movzx   eax, byte ptr [esi+edi]
    mov     al, Decipher[eax-65]
    mov     buffer[edi], al 
    inc     edi
    cmp     edi, 10
    jb      L2
    mov     word ptr buffer[edi], 0A0Dh

    mov     eax, fileHandle
    mov     edx, OFFSET buffer
    mov     ecx, BUFFER_SIZE
    call    WriteToFile

    add     esi, 11             ; Move to the 2nd input string (or after it)
    cmp     esi, offset Cipher_Str + 22
    jb      L1
```